# changing string cases without built in functions

Tags: javascript

```
 function upcase(string) {
    var up = '';

    for (var x = 0; x < string.length; x++) {
        if (string[x] >=97 && string[x]<=122)
            temp+= string[x] - 32;

        else if(string[x]>=65 && string[x]<=90)
            temp+=string[x] + 32;
    }
      return up;
}
```

Hi good evening i am currently working on a practice question that i am doing to prepare for an exam coming up. i am having problems with writing a function that will change the cases of a string from lower to uppercase. not sure what i should be changing or what i should add. any help would be appericated.

Comment: You're probably looking for `String#charCodeAt`

Comment: @Li357 does `charCodeAt()` count as a built in function?

Comment: @Mark_M I suspect that means no `toUppercase` etc. How else would you get character codes other than a hardcoded lookup table?

Comment: @Li357 no idea — I was just curious where the line between built-in and *built-in* was with these sorts of questions.

Comment: I think you have to use 'String.charCodeAt(0)'  function for converting the string to ASCII.

Comment: After the edits, there is no question here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function for this like:

```
function toUpper(string) {
return string.split('').map(c => {
    switch(c) {
        case 'a': return 'A';
        case 'b': return 'B';
        case 'c': return 'C';
        case 'd': return 'D';
        case 'e': return 'E';
        case 'f': return 'F';
        case 'g': return 'G';
        case 'h': return 'H';
        case 'i': return 'I';
        case 'j': return 'J';
        case 'k': return 'K';
        case 'l': return 'L';
        case 'm': return 'M';
        case 'n': return 'N';
        case 'o': return 'O';
        case 'p': return 'P';
        case 'q': return 'Q';
        case 'r': return 'R';
        case 's': return 'S';
        case 't': return 'T';
        case 'u': return 'U';
        case 'v': return 'V';
        case 'w': return 'W';
        case 'x': return 'X';
        case 'y': return 'Y';
        case 'z': return 'Z';
        default: return c;
    }
}).join('');
```

All you need to do now is invoke it with your input string like this:

```
toUpper('This iS a teSt');
```

Which outputs:

**"THIS IS A TEST"**

Answer (score 0):

A more brute force approach results in a function like:

```
function toUpper(str) {
    let upperStr = '';
    for(let i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
        switch(str[i]) {
            case 'a': upperStr+= 'A'; break;
            case 'b': upperStr+= 'B'; break;
            case 'c': upperStr+= 'C'; break;
            case 'd': upperStr+= 'D'; break;
            case 'e': upperStr+= 'E'; break;
            case 'f': upperStr+= 'F'; break;
            case 'g': upperStr+= 'G'; break;
            case 'h': upperStr+= 'H'; break;
            case 'i': upperStr+= 'I'; break;
            case 'j': upperStr+= 'J'; break;
            case 'k': upperStr+= 'K'; break;
            case 'l': upperStr+= 'L'; break;
            case 'm': upperStr+= 'M'; break;
            case 'n': upperStr+= 'N'; break;
            case 'o': upperStr+= 'O'; break;
            case 'p': upperStr+= 'P'; break;
            case 'q': upperStr+= 'Q'; break;
            case 'r': upperStr+= 'R'; break;
            case 's': upperStr+= 'S'; break;
            case 't': upperStr+= 'T'; break;
            case 'u': upperStr+= 'U'; break;
            case 'v': upperStr+= 'V'; break;
            case 'w': upperStr+= 'W'; break;
            case 'x': upperStr+= 'X'; break;
            case 'y': upperStr+= 'Y'; break;
            case 'z': upperStr+= 'Z'; break;
            default: upperStr+= str[i];
        }
    }

    return upperStr;
}
```

Invoking it with `toUpper('This iS a teSt')` results in the expected output `"THIS IS A TEST"`